# input issues back into BIM 360 via Excel

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

BIM 360 can export out issues via Excel, just wonder if it's doable to input back to BIM 360 via Excel? not necessarily create new issues, just modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, please check this cool sample from my colleague Petr:

https://github.com/petrbroz/bim360-issue-editor

It supports exporting and importing BIM360 issues

Here is the demo: https://bim360-issue-editor.herokuapp.com/
Check instruction here for using the demos: https://github.com/petrbroz/bim360-issue-editor#web-application